# Loading Base64 encoded Image in Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, iphone, ios, cocos2d-x

In `Cocos2d-x` I am trying to load a base64 encoded image string to create a sprite. somewhere there seems to be a mistake though because bool ok always returns false. Maybe anybody can help me?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
std::string source = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K....."

int len = 0;
unsigned char *buffer;

len = base64Decode((unsigned char*)source.c_str(), (unsigned int)source.length(), &buffer);

CCImage* img = new CCImage(); 
bool ok = img->initWithImageData(buffer,len);
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Cocos2DX but I'm guessing the string you pass to `base64Decode` needs to be stripped of the meta-data at the front.

Comment: Thank you so much!! that was the problem.. with the stripped metadata it works perfectly.. sometimes i'm blind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MarkRansom answers the OP's question:

> I don't know anything about Cocos2DX but I'm guessing the string you pass to base64Decode needs to be stripped of the meta-data at the front.